# Add results do datagridview

Tags: c#, image, file

I am trying to make an app that finds all images on a specific folder (exemple: CR7) and not on all directories. I have a network share and a lot of directories where I can find that specific folder "CR7". I only need images from that CR7 folder. I cand find them and trying to put those results on a datadridview, but without success. Any ideas why `filesList` does not go to datatable?
Here is the code:

```
{
    public partial class FormProcuraFotos : Form
    {
        DataTable tableWithPhotos;
        public FormProcuraFotos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += this.Worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create the new DataTable to be used
            tableWithPhotos = new DataTable();
            //Find files on a specific folder (CR7)
            string allDir = @"\\share\folder01";
            var CR7Directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(allDir, "CR7", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            List<string> extensions = new List<string>() { ".jpg", ".bmp", ".png", ".tiff", ".gif" };
            List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var dir in CR7Directories)
            {
                List<string> FileNames = new DirectoryInfo(dir).EnumerateFiles(dir)
                                                               .Where(x => extensions.Contains(x.Extension))
                                                               .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
                filesList.AddRange(FileNames);
            }
            // And now here we will add all the files that it has found into the DataTable
            foreach (string entryFiles in filesList)
            {
                DataRow row = tableWithPhotos.NewRow();
                row[0] = Path.GetFileName(entryFiles);
                row[1] = entryFiles;
                tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(entryFiles), entryFiles);
            }
        }
        private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
            var formToOpen = new FormResultadosFotos(tableWithPhotos);
            formToOpen.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be: `tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(row);`  Why the form isn't showing your data we don't know.  You would have to post that code, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are adding new row to datagridview like a datatable and it doen's work.
With datagridview, you can do:

```
tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(entryFiles), entryFiles);
```

Or [If there is any row in your datagridview], you can do:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)tableWithPhotos.Rows[0].Clone();
row[0] = Path.GetFileName(entryFiles);
row[1] = entryFiles;
tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(row);
```

Please refer this link for more details: [DataGridViewRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_Rows)

Because you are creating new form and add a datagrid to it, then the result is null. You can do as bellow:

option1: make filesList as a member of the class, and create new form base on filesList instead of the DataGridView tableWithPhotos, and add row to DataGridView in FormResultadosFotos similar with common your current code.

```
var formToOpen = new FormResultadosFotos(filesList);
formToOpen.Show();
```

option 2: modify your constructor of FormResultadosFotos:

```
        public FormResultadosFotos(DataGridView dataGridView)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].Value, row.Cells[1].Value);
            }
        }
```

P/S: Make sure that your DataGridView in your FormResultadosFotos already had 2 columns.

Cheer!

Comment: No. Does not work: `DataRow row = tableWithPhotos.NewRow();
                row[0] = Path.GetFileName(entryFiles);
                row[1] = entryFiles;
                tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(entryFiles), entryFiles);`

Comment: Hi, Interesting! Did you debug it, and make sure that there are data in filesList?

Comment: Yes, @Nhan Phan

Comment: How many columns in row in the tableWithPhotos you have?
I have just tested with dummy data from my side and it worked: foreach (string entryFiles in filesList)
            {
                var path = "path";
                tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(entryFiles), entryFiles);
            }

Comment: `dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 2;
 dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
 dataGridView2.DataSource = table;
 DataGridViewCellStyle columnHeaderStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
 columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
 columnHeaderStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
 dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle;
 dataGridView2.Columns[0].Name = "Filename";
  dataGridView2.Columns[1].Name = "Ctrl+C";`

Comment: Could you please try to use this way: "tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(entryFiles), entryFiles);" ?

Comment: Same results. Datagridview has no data, only the column header names

Comment: hmm i think your datagridview name is dataGridView2 and tableWithPhotos is other  form. maybe that is root cause.

Comment: Yes, I have a datagridview on another form that show this results.